# Android Seekbar: adding extra space around thumb

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I need to keep the size of thumb and other functionalities as default (like scale on touch) but I need to add the space between progress lines:

[image: seekbar]

To add more description: how to widen the purple area without affecting anything else?
[image: seekbar widen]

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, there is not way to change that gap size without affecting the thumb drawable, So I used a ring `<shape>` and made it look like an oval, and made it smaller, and had fixed and equal sizes for all `<selector>`s inside the shape tag.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="1000"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="8dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
            <size
                android:width="16dp"
                android:height="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```